# Could not generate launcher icons PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/app_logo.png'

Tags: android, flutter

I was trying to create an app logo for my app, since I'm about to deploy and release it, but here's the issue. I was trying to let the terminal generate the launcher icons which I copied the code from the website:

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
```

However when I ran this code on the terminal, this was the result:

```
 Warning: flutter_icons has been deprecated please use flutter_launcher_icons instead in your yaml files
• Creating default icons Android

✕ Could not generate launcher icons
PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/app_logo.png' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
, errno = 2)
```

I already added the icon launcher package code on my pubsec.yaml:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

flutter_icons:
   android: true
   ios: true
   image_path: "assets/app_logo.png"
```

But for some reason, the system couldn't find the specific image file, like I already made sure that the image file name is typed properly in my pubsecyaml( as seen above ) based from the project IRC:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxDds.png)

But I still don't understand what's the issue, can somebody please help me so I can properly fix this.

I'm expecting the system to read the image file properly to generate the launcher icons.

Answer (score 0):

as the error suggested:

```
flutter_icons has been deprecated please use flutter_launcher_icons
```

Remove the old package from pubspec and Use the updated package : [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

```
flutter_launcher_icons:
   android: true
   ios: true
   image_path: "assets/app_logo.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/app_logo.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21
```

If you look at your error it shows that flutter_icon has been depreciated, use [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

Comment: I already used that updated package code, but this was till the issue/result when I ran it again in the terminal:Could not generate launcher icons
PathNotFoundException:  Cannot open file, path = 'assets/app_logo.png' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
, errno = 2)

Comment: I think you should consider checking file path, check once again if there is any typo or something in path or image name

Comment: Try adding lib to the path name e.g. `lib/assets/app_logo.png` . Tell me if it works

Comment: I already got it to work earlier, again thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please describe what was issue and how you fixed it